Jewish king declaring a Nazirite vow
The Torah mandates that as part of any normal Nezirus, that person may not cut their hair until the end (which is never less than 30 days minimum if no term was specified). On the other hand, a Jewish king must get a haircut everyday. Does he violate his Nezirus and take a haircut, or does he violate the rules of his kingship and not cut his hair?
Additionally, at the end of a Nezirus, they shave off all their hair. Would the king also do so, even though it would look embarrassing and disrespectful of the monarchy?

Consider Mishna Nazir 3:6

Talmud Nazir 5a (regarding Avshalom) would seem to indicate that he would shave his hair.
